# 401 http error only in real android device, 200 success code in genymotion

Tags: android, http, webservice-client, http-status-code-401, android-async-http

My problem is, when i am logging in to my `webservice`, i am getting `401` error code. But i am getting this error code only in real android devices(i have tried this in 2 different phones and networks).
But in genymotion i am not getting any error, instead i am getting `200` success code. And my application is working perfectly.

I also would like to inform you that, my code is working fine in other connection parts of my application for both real and virtual devices;  such as requesting data etc. which requires authentication

Somewhere in util class

```
static public AsyncHttpClient setHeader(Context contex,AsyncHttpClient client){

String username =contex.getResources().getString(R.string.url_login_username);
String password = contex.getResources().getString(R.string.url_login_password);

//since its required for this webservice
client.addHeader("Authorization","Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString(
        (username + ":" + password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP
));

return client;
}
```

In the `login fragment`

```
client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client  = Utils.setHeader(getActivity(), client);
```

In the callback of client  , i have overwritten `onFailure` function as

```
@Override
public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2, Throwable arg3)     {
   String string = new String(arg2);
   Log.d("LoginFragment onFailure", "" + arg0 +" "+string);
   showSnackbar(R.string.loginAccessProblem, Color.RED);
}
```

And i am getting this erorr in `logcat`

```
onFailure﹕ 401 {"status":false,"error":"Not authorized"}
```

I have also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110497/asynchttpclient-authentication-failed) tried code below

```
client.setBasicAuth(getString(R.string.url_login_username),getString(R.string.url_login_password));
```

edit : I can say my virtual device and webservice are in the same network, real devices has to connect from outer network

Comment: It could be a server bit if the same code works in the emulator and not in the physical device, can you explain how the server authentication and authorization is?

Comment: Seems that either the server is not allowing you to connect from outer network or you are connecting to a different server

Comment: I had the same issue. In my case, I was sending a timestamp (base encoded) as one of the headers. The device's (in which I was testing) time was set to a past time which made authorization failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. I am getting my connection urls from xml file. Devices have different languages, genymotion is in english, real devices are in local language. So my application was getting its urls from values-tr xml in another library which my app project has dependency on. 
So avoid this problem in the future , i have gathered all my url connections in same language xml file(general one) and removed in language xmls.